# Animating an imported SVG object

Tags: svg, raphael

I've decided to use svg.js instead of raphael.js because i only need simple animate functions for my SVG images, and it's much smaller in size with a nice syntax.

I have the SVG import working successfully, but i'm unable to figure out which object i should be referring to, to animate it.

The final bit of my code after the import says

```
var rawSvg = 'svg raw data here'
var draw = svg('paper').size('100%', '100%');
    draw.import(rawSvg);
```

I inspected the elements in Google Chrome, and all i could see was the SVG object, "g", #path1layer1 and Path2993. So tried to apply the animate method to each one of them, but i get an error to say that the object does not have an animate method. So which object should i bind the animate method to?

This is the last thing i tried

```
path2993.animate().move(150, 150);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [svg.import.js](https://github.com/wout/svg.import.js) plugin has been updated. Now all imported elements are referenced in the object returned by the import() method, as [mentioned here](https://github.com/wout/svg.import.js#references):

```
var rawSvg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  --><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"    width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve"><line id="line1234" fill="none" stroke="#FF7BAC" stroke-width="20" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="138.682" y1="250" x2="293.248" y2="95.433"/><rect id="rect1235" x="22.48" y="19.078" fill="#F7931E" stroke="#C1272D" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="94.972" height="94.972"/><path id="path1236" opacity="0.5" fill="#29ABE2" d="M189.519,131.983c0,5.523-4.477,10-10,10H92.257c-5.523,0-10-4.477-10-10V53.659 c0-5.523,4.477-10,10-10h87.262c5.523,0,10,4.477,10,10V131.983z"/><circle id="circle1237" opacity="0.8" fill="#8CC63F" cx="201.603" cy="159.508" r="69.067"/><polygon id="polygon1238" fill="none" stroke="#8C6239" stroke-width="20" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="286.331,287.025  227.883,271.365 212.221,212.915 255.009,170.127 313.459,185.789 329.119,244.237 "/></svg>';
var draw = svg('paper');
var store = draw.import(rawSvg);
store.polygon1238.fill('#f06');
```

Comment: OK, so i updated the library, and now my code looks like this

    var draw = svg('paper').size('100%', '100%');
  var store = draw.import(rawSvg);


that should work yes? although i still get "object has now method animate"

    
    store.animate().move(150, 150);

Comment: That is because "store" is an object containing the imported elements. You should be able to target them like this: store.polygon1238.animate(200).fill('#f06');

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading the docs and it's not clear to me. But couldn't you add an id attribute to the `this.SVG` object and then access the svg element via standard DOM method?  Or are you trying to retrieve the js object itself?  Wouldn't that be the var that you call draw on, or is that too late?

Comment: I honestly don't know.
I'd be happy to be able to access the SVG object, I don't need to have to access the JS object, since i just want to manipulate the SVG in the DOM.

Where exactly would i add the ID attribute?

Comment: I keep checking the DOM properties, and the id shows as path2993, so it's strange why this doesnt work.

I did the same thing using Raphael.js and just supplied the path name and it worked fine.

Comment: You can get an element with: SVG.get('element_id')

Answer (score 0):

The [svg.js](http://svgjs.com) import plugin is very young. All imported elements are actually built with [svg.js](http://svgjs.com) so they are all exposed within [svg.js](http://svgjs.com) using the children() method:

```
var draw = svg('paper');
draw.import('... svg data ... ');
draw.children().forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element.attr('id');
});
```

But if you want to reference elements individually it is better to create them individually rather than importing a huge document of SVG. Let's say you want to use a path generated in Inkscape, just create the single shape and save it as plain svg. Open the svg file, locate the `<path>` tag and copy the contents of the `d="..."` attribute, which may look something like this:

```
M 8.7185878,4.0337352 -2.2072895,0.01601326 8.7185884,-4.0017078 c -1.7454984,2.3720609 -1.7354408,5.6174519 -6e-7,8.035443 z
```

Then you can create and animate the path:

```
var pathData = 'M 8.7185878,4.0337352 -2.2072895,0.01601326 8.7185884,-4.0017078 c -1.7454984,2.3720609 -1.7354408,5.6174519 -6e-7,8.035443 z';
var draw = svg('paper');
var path = draw.path(pathData).size(30).move(10,10);
path.animate().move(100,100);
```